# What is the equivalent of these properties for Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

I have this proprieties in the style.css

**CODE CSS:**

```
width: calc(100% - 120px);
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

How can I replace these values on safari browsers? There are common values ?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I have Safari 5.1.7 version

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276

Comment: There is no need to support Safari v5 in 2017, given that it's 5 years old.

Comment: If you need to support Safari, because the users of your website have it (that would be v10), but you only have a Windows machine to develop on, you're out of luck.